# Как описать max_element у вектора класса?

Tags: c++, классы, vector

Есть класс CarShop, содержащий в себе следующий переменные:

```
std::string name;
int yearOfCreation;
int engineCapacity;
int price;
```

А также соответствующие get-методы

При попытке поиска макс. элемента выдаёт ошибку компилятора 2100.

Как нужно правильно описать `max_element()`?

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");
std::vector<CarShop> car;

int size = 0;
    std::string name;
    int yearOfCreation;
    int engineCapacity;
    int price;

int choise = 0;
do {
    //Заполняем класс
    car.resize(size);
    cout << "\nВведите марку для " << size + 1 << "-й машины: ";
    cin >> name;
    cout << "Введите год выпуска для " << size + 1 << "-й машины: ";
    cin >> yearOfCreation;
    cout << "Введите объём двигателя для " << size + 1 << "-й машины: ";
    cin >> engineCapacity;
    cout << "Введите цену для " << size + 1 << "-й машины: ";
    cin >> price;


    car.insert(car.begin() + size, CarShop(name, yearOfCreation, engineCapacity, price));
    size++;
    //Заполняем класс      END

    //Предлагаем юзеру добавить машину
    do {
        std::cout << "  Добавить еще одну машину?\n\t 1 - ДА\n\t 0 - НЕТ\n";
        cin >> choise;
    } while (choise > 1 || choise < 0);
    //Предлагаем юзеру добавить машину     END

} while (choise == 1);


//Поиск макс. элемента
std::max_element(car[0].getEngineCapacity(), car[size].getEngineCapacity());



system("pause");
return 0;
```

Comment: Кстати  car.insert(car.begin() + size, CarShop());  Это то же самое, что и car.push_back(CarShop()) И что значит //Заполняем класс?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Примерно так -

```
std::max_element(car.begin(),car.end(),
                 [](const CarShop& a, const CarShop& b)
                 { return a.getEngineCapacity() < b.getEngineCapacity()});
```

Только не забудьте воспользоваться тем, что эта функция возвращает, а то вы ее как-то вызвали, а результат не использовали...